# How to unit test for http request inside a function in directive

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, directive

I have made a function inside a http request is made for get and then post request how can I test that method here is my directive controller function:

```
var getConfig = function () {
    if (!$scope.json) {
        $http.get('/schools/' + $scope.school.id + '/config?deployment_uuid=' + $scope.schoolId)
                .then(function (response) {
                    $scope.school.config = JSON.stringify(response.data, null, 4);
                });
    }
};

$scope.disable = function () {
    getConfig();
    $http.post('/school/' + $scope.school.id + '/update', {
        deployment_id: $scope.schoolId,
        component: $scope.schoolName,
        is_enabled: false,
        config: JSON.parse($scope.school.config)
    });
};
```

testcase:

```
  describe('controller', function () {
        fit('should POST payload  for a scenario to disable', function () {
            $scope.school.config = JSON.stringify(mockSchoolConfig, null, 4);
            $scope.disable();
            $scope.$digest();
            $httpBackend.expect('POST', '/school/' + $scope.school.id + '/update', {
                deployment_id: $scope.schoolId,
                component: $scope.schoolName,
                is_enabled: false,
                config: $scope.school.config
            }).respond(200);
            //$httpBackend.flush();
        });
    });

Error: Unexpected request: GET /s/create-alarm/config?school_uuid=170bf60e-0153-4615-9a4e-a6bc3ad546ea
```

No more request expected

How can test this function and http request?

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you're mixing setup, request and handling code. While it's convenient to write such code, it's hard to test (as you noticed). The solution is to split the code into parts, probably each into a distinct function:

```
var requestConfig() {
    return $http.get('/schools/' + $scope.school.id + '/config?deployment_uuid=' + $scope.schoolId);
}

var saveConfig(response) {
    $scope.school.config = JSON.stringify(response.data, null, 4);
}

var getConfig = function () {
    if (!$scope.json) {
        requestConfig()
                .then(function (response) {
                    saveConfig();
                });
    }
};
```

In your tests, you can now mock the functions. For example, you can replace `requestConfig()` with a function which just returns an object without making the request.

You may also want to avoid using global variables like `$scope` and instead pass the information around via function arguments to make writing the tests easier.